# Windows Defender seems to be flagging Java applications

Tags: java, windows-defender, log4j

I'm trying to evaluate some software tools (ERD diagrams) and have downloaded dbSchema and ModelXtractor.  Attempting to install either tool results in a Windows Defender popup:

[image]

dbSchema provides three different packges, a self-extracting .exe, a .msi and a .zip file.  The first two flag on attempting to launch. The .zip can be extracted, but attempting to run the app executable also alerts.

The vendor provides md5 checksums on their website, and all three files (.exe, .msi and .zip) match.

Is Windows Defender alerting on vulnerable versions of log4j?

I did a Google search and didn't find anything.

Comment: That message is at least usually displayed when a program that MS doesn't have on file is executed, or if the application is unsigned.

Comment: This seems to be new behavior, as I have never seen this popup before (been using Windows since ... 3.0)

Comment: correct, it started with Win10 I believe, and is part of the Windows defender integration. see if any of the advice here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946680/how-to-avoid-the-windows-defender-smartscreen-prevented-an-unrecognized-app-fro

Comment: If it is a valid app (for you to say) click on Run Anyway and there should not be issues going forward . I have see this message for over a year on some apps.  Saw it with Ubiquit.

Comment: “Is Windows Defender alerting on vulnerable versions of log4j?” - No; Windows Smartscreen is based on a files reputation. The reputation of the file is based on multiple factors including the number of people who have downloaded the file.  Additionally, the file can be properly digitally signed, which doesn’t appear to be the case for that file. If you trust the publisher then you should allow the file to execute.

Comment: @Ramhound Please post that as the answer so I can accept it... I'd flag this as a dup of the link provided by FrankThomas but SE doesn't allow cross-site dups.

Comment: I would normally answer a question like this but the only question asked is a yes/no answer. Unfortunately, my knowledge about smart screen is based on decades of tribal knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of log4j have a critical safety bug. Maybe you have it because of this bug.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).